# Mathcad function definition cross reference

Tags: loops, self-reference, mathcad

Hi I have a problem with the definition of functions.
I have a function A that references to function B which uses function A from a previous iteration.

here's my code

[image]

thanks for helping me

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Mathcad doesn't allow mutual function calls.  One way round the problem is to define a generic function that encompasses all of your intended behaviour and then use an extra input parameter to select which part of the function you want to evaluate.   See image below.

I note that your first function θ<sub>a</sub> is recursive for t >= 5 s.  You also have a variable θ<sub>a</sub> in the second function c<sub>a</sub> and a variable h<sub>net</sub> in the fourth function Δ<sub>a.t</sub>

[image]